# Can't retrieve text from a span class using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am having trouble extracting a rating text inside a span class.

Already tried the following XPATH:

```
response.xpath("//i/span[@class='a-icon-alt']/text()").getall()
response.xpath('//span[@data-hook="rating-out-of-text"]/text()').getall()
```

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="a-fixed-left-grid AverageCustomerReviews a-spacing-small">
  <div class="a-fixed-left-grid-inner" style="padding-left:105px">
    <div class="a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left" style="width:105px;margin-left:-105px;float:left;">
      <i data-hook="average-star-rating" class="a-icon a-icon-star-medium a-star-medium-4 averageStarRating">
        <span class="a-icon-alt">3,8 de 5 estrelas</span>
      </i>
    </div>
    <div class="a-fixed-left-grid-col aok-align-center a-col-right" style="padding-left:0%;float:left;">
      <div class="a-row">
        <span class="a-size-base a-nowrap">
          <span data-hook="rating-out-of-text" class="a-size-medium a-color-base">3,8 de 5</span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If it helps, the HTML was extracted from this page:

https://www.amazon.com.br/Cookpad-inc/dp/B086MT7THB/ref=sr_1_12?brr=1&qid=1662666482&rd=1&s=alexa-skills&sr=1-12

Comment: You can try the XPath's without the `/text()` suffix. Maybe this helps.

Comment: It looks like the text that you are trying to get is loaded dynamically. To verify that, test it on scrapy shell with the same url and open the page in browser using `view(response)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to grab it using this:  The span isn't the immediate parent of the text, so using the `//` means it will pull the text from any decendant of the element.

```
response.xpath('//span[@data-hook="rating-out-of-text"]//text()').getall()
```

---

###### Update

If you are using scrapy... a great way of finding out if the scrapy response is different than what you observe in your webbrowser is using the `open_in_browser` function.  Then you can actually see what page looks like from your spiders point of view.

for example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
    ...
    start_urls = [...]

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        ...
```

Comment: I tried it. It works on the code snippet, but for some reason, I don't understand it doesn't work on the page.

Comment: @leo  Then the issue isn't the xpath expression.  It is probably because it is either rendered by javascript or because amazon is using some sort of anti web-crawler procedure that blocks you from access to the actual page.

Comment: I can use XPath to get data at the beginning of the page. But I can't use it after the description part of the page. I suspected that it could be due to some Javascript or something like that.

Comment: @Leo  See update to my answer for a good tip to check what is happening

Comment: Alexander, thanks for your help. I used view(response) on Scrapy shell and was able to understand the problem. It looks like that part of the page is rendered by javascript by Amazon.

Comment: Is there any way to render the javascript to make it available for Scrapy?

Comment: @leo Not with scrapy alone, no.  You would need to use selenium or playwright, or something similar in order to properly render everything the way the browser does.